# Feign client Retryer with a new request interceptor?

Tags: java, interceptor, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am currently building a feign client manually and passing Interceptors to it for authorization. I would like to have a smarter Retryer for some Response code.

```
public class myErrorEncoder extends ErrorDecoder.Default {

@Override
public Exception decode(final String methodKey, final Response response) {
    if (response.status() == 401) {
        String token = refreshToken();  // I would like to refresh the token and Edit the client
        return new RetryableException("Token Expired will retry it", null);
    } else {
        return super.decode(methodKey, response);
    }
}
```

}

Interceptor

```
@Bean public CustomInterceptor getInterceptor(String token) {
    return new CustomInterceptor(token);}
```

Feign builder

```
 private <T> T feignBuild(final Class<T> clazz, final String uri, final String token) {
    return Feign
            .builder().client(new ApacheHttpClient())
            .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
            .decoder(new ResponseEntityDecoder(feignDecoder())
            .retryer(new Retryer.Default(1,100,3))
            .errorDecoder(new ErrorDecoder())
            .requestInterceptor(getInterceptor(token))
            .contract(new ClientContract())
            .logger(new Slf4jLogger(clazz)).target(clazz, uri);
}
```

Now I would like to update feign client with the refreshed token and retry.
Is there a way get access to the client instance and configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the interceptor is incorrect.  Interceptors are re-applied during a retry, but they are instantiated only once and are expected to be thread safe.  To achieve what you are looking for will need to separate the token generation from the interceptor and have the interceptor request a new token.

```java
public class TokenInterceptor() {
   TokenService tokenService;

   public TokenInterceptor(TokenService tokenService) {
      this.tokenService = tokenService;
   }

   public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
      /* getToken() should create a new token */
      String token = this.tokenService.getToken();
      template.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
   }
}
```

This will ensure that a new token is created each retry cycle.

Comment: Handling it this way would mean that a new token is generated for every request. Which is not optimal. I would want the token generation to happen on 401 error code only.

Comment: You will need to add logic then to determine if a token is required before requesting a new token.  You can use an `ErrorDecoder` to catch the `401` and *clear* the token and return a `RetryableException` to retry the request.

Comment: @KevinDavis Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the solution you proposed will append another Authorization header with the new token.
How do you replace the existing one?

Comment: @sharon182 yes, its append another Auth header. That's why you need to delete the old one first header:
 template.removeHeader("Authorization"); template.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);